# ratchet not connecting to database

Tags: php, ratchet

I have been playing around with ratchet, and installed everything. I have followed the guide lines as well at socketo.me. However, I cannot insert values into my database after postings. I am noticing the `$conn` variable in the `push-server.php` file as well as other files using the same variable in the vendor folder.

Should my connection to the database be the same variable as well? Currently, it is `$con` and that is what I have been using to connect to my database thus far on my website

```html
<?php include("./inc/incfiles/connect.inc.php");
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION["user_log"]))
  {
  $fiwiuser = ""; 
  }
  else
  {
  //$fiwiuser = $_SESSION["email_log"];
 $fiwiuser = $_SESSION["user_log"];
 //$username_send = $_SESSION["username"]; 
  }  
?>

<?php
  $post = strip_tags(@$_POST['body']);
  if ($post !="")
  {
 $entryData = array(
   'body'           =>   strip_tags(@$_POST['body'])
      , 'date_added'     =>   date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
      , 'added_by'       =>   strip_tags(@$_POST['$fiwiuser'])
      , 'user_added_to'  =>   strip_tags(@$_POST['$username'])
 );
 
 $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO posts (body, date_added, added_by, user_added_to) VALUES (body, date_added, added_by, user_added_to)")
      ->execute($entryData['body'], $entryData['date_added'], $entryData['added_by'], $entryData['user_added_to']);
 
 // This is our new stuff
 $context = new ZMQContext();
 $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
 $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
 
 $socket->send(json_encode($entryData));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Not enough information to be helpful here. Please tell us what errors you are getting. How did you pass the database connection into the server? Where's the code?

Comment: The problem is that I am not getting the data posted to mysql database. Something is off.

Comment: I get that, but the fact that you haven't bothered to search your error log for any errors isn't going to help you get any closer to what is off. For example, this code is clearly going to throw a PDO exception if you bother putting [PDO into Exception mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Comment: Oh I see, I am doing it the PDO way. I am not that savy with error logs and stuff. But thanks for your help.